# Error in uploading the artifact to s3 bucket using jenkins job

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket is in this region: null. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: 3122F6D5F7722BB5), S3 Extended Request ID: 
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1343)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:961)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:448)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:397)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:378)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4039)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1583)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Build step 'Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue : Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=devopsteam/Patient-Portal/apk/, file=android-debug.apk region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=true managed=true , server encryption false
ERROR: Failed to upload files
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket is in this region: null. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: A127621732F2F71D), S3 Extended Request ID:

Comment: so what should be bucket path in  Destination bucket  ? s3:// or devopsteam/Patient-Portal/apk/